# Login with Amazon (LWA), has one customer exactly one user_id?

Tags: amazon-pay, login-with-amazon

The question is about the "Login with Amazon" user id in form of `amzn1.account.A123456789`.

(1) For one user, is this user id the same for all web sites using LWA? Oder does each registered web site get a different user id from Amazon for the same user?

(2) For one user, is this user id the same for "Login with Amazon" and for "Pay with Amazon"? or are there two different ids for one user?

I am asking because we are porting an existing shop database to a new web shop system. We thought (hoped) that we can use the existing Amazon IDs from the old database to identify the users in the new system. But first tests show that the ids are different.

What's also confusing is the documentation [https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/login-with-amazon/customer-profile.html]

It reads:

> Every company that creates websites or apps for Login with Amazon gets the same user_id for a customer. However, when a customer logs in to another company's app or site, the user_id will be different. This is so user_id cannot be used to track customers across the Web.

For me, both sentences are contradictory.

Comment: That explanation is indeed a little confusing. I believe, they try to say that the user_id will be the same *within* one company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The User IDs are not identical between different merchants. If you use the same merchantId for the new system, you should get the same User IDs.

(2) Login and Pay User IDs are the same

Comment: Thank you very much for this precise answer! I can now confirm that both points (1) and (2) are correct. It is also worth mentioning that even if the existing shop system used Client-ID + PublicKey from the AmazonPay configuration, you can also get a Client-Secret there, which you can use for a pure Login-with-Amazon procedure.

Comment: And it is also worth mentioning that it is enough that the MerchantId is the same (as you wrote), you can still use multiple ClientIds. We are currently merging two online shops into one new one. And because the MerchantId is the same in all 3 cases, the AmazonId for one user stays the same.

Comment: @eikuh Thanks for adding this additional information 